# Postman Test with comparison to global variable

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I want to orchestrate two requests in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). The first response will give me a variable. I save this id to a global variable `id`. In Postman this variable is usually accessible via `{{id}}`.

Then I send a second request with this id (like `GET foo.bar/{{id}}`). Now I want to check, if the id is in the result as well.

This is what I tried in the test code:

```
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.id).to.eql({{id}});
```

where `id`is the variable from the first response (e.g. `72b302bf297a228a75730123efef7c41`).

The response for the second request looks sth. like this:

```
{
    "id": "72b302bf297a228a75730123efef7c41"
}
```

Here some examples which did not work either:

```
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.id).to.eql("{{id}}");
```

```
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    var myId = {{id}};
    pm.expect(jsonData.id).to.eql(myId);
```

My **excpectation** is, that the test will be positive and the `id  from the request will be found in the response.

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

*Thanks for the help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{...}}` syntax cannot be used like that, in the sandbox environment, you would need to access it this way.

`pm.expect(jsonData.id).to.eql(pm.globals.get('id'))`

The test syntax would be:

```
pm.test("IDs equal?", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.id).to.eql(pm.globals.get('id'))
});
```

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for the help. I tried 

```pm.test("IDs equal?", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.id).to.eql('{{id}}');
});```
The programm does not allow to cast the id variable before, so that `...to.eql('id')` is not possible (as far as I know).

Here is the surrounding code:
```pm.test("IDs equal?", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.id).to.eql('{{id}}');
});```

Is there any way to get the id as variable into the `eql(.)`?

Comment: I wrote the correct expect statement for you, did you try that. That works, if you have `id` variable stored at the global level from a previous request.

Comment: what I didn't saw was the `pm.globals.get()`. My bad. You gave the right hint. The following code works:
```pm.test("IDs equal?", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.id).to.eql(pm.collectionVariables.get('id'));
});```

Comment: So you didn't save this as a `global` variable, as you mentioned in the original question. :)